# Showing that an exponential-like function eventually catches up with a polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> You are given a finite set  $A$ of prime numbers. Let $A=\{a_1, a_2\cdots\}$. Let B be the set formed of numbers that are formed by multiplying powers of $a_i$ i.e. $B=\{t|t=a_1^{e_1}\cdots a_2^{e_2},e_i\ge 0\}$. Now let us order the elements of $B$. Let $B=\{b_1,b_2,\cdots\}$ with $b_1<b_2<\cdots$. Prove that for all $k$, there exists an $n$ such that $b_n>n^k$.

So I was trying to solve a different problem and reached to the conclusion that this seemingly obvious statement(which I for some reason can't find a proof of) finishes off the problem nicely. I tried to induct on $k$, $|A|$ but they did not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** A good answer has been given by Element118. Let me summarize what I have learnt from his solution for my own benefit.

1)The most important thing to do in this problem is to create an upper bound on the number of elements of $B$ below any number $N$.

2)With that in view, it is natural for a person to try and find a very easy-to-deal-with upperbound.

The rest of the solution is quite natural and does not require any special insight(I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a large number $N$ and the number of values in $B$ less than $N$. Suppose $k>10$, otherwise $b_n>n^{10}\geq n^k$.

We can fit at most $\log_{a_i}N$ powers of each prime. We can bound the total number of values in $B$ to less than $(\log_2 N)^{|A|}$.

Let $n = \left\lceil(\log_2 N)^{|A|}\right\rceil$. We have shown $b_n>N$. It suffices to ensure $N\geq n^k$ by setting $N$ appropriately.

Rewriting $N=2^{2^{k|A|}}$, we obtain $n^k=(2^{k|A|})^{k|A|}=2^{k^2|A|^2}$.

As $k|A|>10$, it is easy to show that $2^{k|A|}\geq k^2|A|^2$.

$$\log_2 N=2^{k|A|}\geq k^2|A|^2=\log_2 \left(n^k\right)$$